# Executing Procedure Oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, procedure

So I have the following procedure created on Oracle 11g:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE calc_fee
(proc_borrowed_date IN Borrowing.borrowed_date%TYPE,
proc_return_date IN Borrowing.return_date%TYPE,
proc_fee OUT number)
IS
BEGIN
proc_fee := (SYSDATE - proc_return_date) * 2;
END calc_fee;​
```

How can I execute it? I've already tried

```
EXEC CALC_FEE(SYSDATE - 10, SYSDATE);
```

and

EXECUTE CALC_FEE(SYSDATE - 10, SYSDATE);

But they all return me ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a procedure using `call` (instead of `exec`), or in a PL/SQL code block. Also note that you have three parameters, so you'll want to pass a variable to catch the output parameter:

```
declare
  V_FEE number;
begin
  CALC_FEE(SYSDATE - 10, SYSDATE, V_FEE);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_FEE);
end;
```

Instead of a procedure with an `out` parameter, you can also make a function which returns the value:

```
create or replace FUNCTION calc_fee
(proc_borrowed_date IN Borrowing.borrowed_date%TYPE,
proc_return_date IN Borrowing.return_date%TYPE) return number
IS
BEGIN
  return (SYSDATE - proc_return_date) * 2;
END calc_fee;
```

Such a function can even be used in a query:

```
select CALC_FEE(SYSDATE - 10, SYSDATE) from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the output parameter as well, as below:

```
declare
  pf number;
begin
  calc_fee(sysdate, sysdate-10, pf);
  dbms_output.put_line('pf is ' || pf);
end;
```

**Reference**:

[Developing and Using Stored Procedures on Oracle® Database 2 Day Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm)